# time data '2022-11-27T23:40:26' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' how can chnge this format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

my df['time'] is 2022-11-27T23:40:26 this format i want to change in %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S this format
how can i do

Need solution in above problem/sformat

Answer (score 0):

- First make your datetime string to a pandas datetime type with [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)
- Then convert it back to any other datetime string you like using [pd.Series.dt.strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

Your code could look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"time": ["2022-11-27T23:40:26", "2022-12-28T10:12:26"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
df["time_formatted"] = df["time"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```